# How to overwrite linux system files into the yocto filesystem?

Tags: linux, yocto, recipe, rootfs

I am new, yocto build at `imx6q` embedded system.

I want to overwrite linux system files after do_rootfs. For example, target system files are below.

- /etc/network/interface
- /etc/issue
- /etc/init.d/rcS
- /home/root/mytest.sh

so, i made custom layer and custom recipe.
helloworld binary is copy ok.
**but, do_mytask function is not called.**

what's wrong with my code?
or any other method for my purpose.

```
#
# This file was derived from the 'Hello World!' example recipe in the
# Yocto Project Development Manual.
#
SUMMARY = "Simple helloworld application"
SECTION = "examples"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "file://helloworld.c"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_compile() {
         ${CC} helloworld.c -o helloworld
}

do_install() {
         install -d ${D}${bindir}
         install -m 0755 helloworld ${D}${bindir}
}   

FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
SRC_URI += " \
  file://interfaces \
  file://issue \
  file://mytest.sh \
"

addtask mytask after do_rootfs before do_image
do_mytask() {
         install -d ${D}/etc/network
         cp -af ${WORKDIR}/interfaces ${D}/etc/network/interfaces
         cp -af ${WORKDIR}/issue ${D}/etc/issue
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You'll need to extend the recipes that provide the files you want to replace.

Using `/etc/network/interfaces` as an example, the first step is to figure out which recipe installs that file.

From the bitbake prompt:

```
$ oe-pkgdata-util find-path /etc/network/interfaces
init-ifupdown: /etc/network/interfaces
```

So this tells us that `/etc/network/interfaces` is installed by the `init-ifupdown` receipe.

A file search shows that `init-ifupdown` is part of poky:

```
$ find . -name init-ifupdown*.bb
./poky/meta/recipes-core/init-ifupdown/init-ifupdown_1.0.bb
```

Now, since you need to modify the output of `init-ifupdown`, you'll need to *extend* `init-ifupdown` by creating a similarly named `.bbappend` in your own layer.

You might create the new `.bbappend` at

```
my-layer/receipes-core/init-ifupdown/init-ifupdown_%.bbappend
```

The `%` is a wildcard that ensures the `.bbappend` will apply to all future versions of the `init-ifupdown` recipe, which is probably what you want.

Place your custom `interfaces` file in a folder below the `.bbappend`:

```
my-layer/receipes-core/init-ifupdown/files/interfaces
```

The `.bbappend` then only needs to contain a single line to enable bitbake to pick up the new `interfaces` file:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
```

Finally, repeat the above with each system file you'd like to replace.

Comment: Do I need to add `init-ifupdown` into the image? Or `init-ifupdown` will always be in the image?

Comment: If you want to use the suggested `.bbappend` to install a custom `interfaces` file, then yes `init-ifupdown` needs to be added to the image

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the file to modify. For example, if you search 'interfaces' in poky directories, you'll find it in 'meta/recipes-core/init-ifupdown/init-ifupdown-${PV}/'. You just need to create a recipe named init-ifupdown-${PV}.bbappend in your meta, recreating the path seen in poky (recipes-core/init-ifupdown/). This recipe can contain a single line :

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
```

Then you create a 'files' folder with the 'interfaces' file you want to have.

For 'issue', like others found in the /etc directory (profile, fstab, ...), it's the same procedure, with the sources in poky/meta/recipes-core/base-files/.

For init.d scripts, use the 'update-rc' class.

Comment: I totally understand.
But I wanted to make it my own layer recipe. just one.

Comment: This is not the way to go. When a file is provided by an existing recipe, it is good practice to extend this recipe (create a bbappend) in order to customize it. All these personalized recipes (and those you created from scratch) must be in your own meta.

Comment: Your solution worked, but it contains a typo: the colon should be put next to the equal for it to work: `:=`.

Answer (score 1):

You recipe is not "image recipe" (and it shouldn't be for hello world) thus you cannot use tasks do_rootfs and do_image in this case. A bit of clarification: image recipe is .bb file that you use to build image with bitbake or devtool (in your case some containing imx6q, you can find them with `bitbake-layers show-recipes "*-image-*"`).

It looks like you are looking really is a way to override do_install of some recipe that installs that mentioned files. Then find what recipe installs those files and create [bbappend](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#using-bbappend-files) file in your top layer. This bbappend file may contain [do_install_append](https://www.toradex.com/community/questions/5253/how-to-addmodify-files-in-the-root-file-systems-in.html) task where you can place your `install <file> <dir>` lines (note, using `cp` as not recommended, everything should be done with install tool).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am beginner and I understood it roughly.
In the end, do you mean making an image recipe? Anyway i will do it your way.

Comment: @devj No, "override do_install of some recipe that installs that mentioned files" means creating bbappend for init-ifupdown in your case. the same as in the link I shared.

Comment: @devj I don't see where you need to copy directory. install "correctly" copies files (cp + chown + chgrp) - single or multiple (with *), check original recipe to get example http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-core/init-ifupdown/init-ifupdown_1.0.bb?h=master

Answer (score 1):

Adding an extra comment based on Carsten Hansen original answer for folks working with Xilinx/Petalinux.

Under Petalinux environment we don't really have the command: oe-pkgdata-util, so the strategy is to do a search in the Xilinx SDK folder. You might have it installed on Linux under **/opt** according to the documentation. If you do a:

```
grep -r syslog-startup.conf .
```

you will see **busybox** recipe being the one that does the installation of the syslog-startup.conf.

You can create the override recipe called busybox_%.bbappend under:

```
../project-spec/meta-user/recipes-core/busybox/
```

Put the modified syslog-startup.conf file under:

```
../project-spec/meta-user/recipes-core/busybox/files/syslog-startup.conf
```

Rebuild via petalinux-build. You can also force the creation of the rootfs via petalinux-build -c rootfs and the system should populate your new file.