# Yocto boot partition vs boot rootfs directory

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto

I need to mount my boot partition in order to perform software updates in my yocto built.
I would expect to mount it in /boot but I see that there is a directory there already

I cant seem to find information about what this /boot directory is and why its needed. It contains the same .itb file that is in the boot partition

Do I need this boot directory? Who is it used by? Is there a way to tell yocto not to create it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that atmel dt overlay was putting overlay files in the
/boot directory. These overlays aren't relevent for my machine so I removed the dt-overlay dependency

https://github.com/linux4sam/meta-atmel/blob/07867084ec52b5580e55eb67c861823eaab5e4c3/recipes-bsp/dt-overlay-at91/dt-overlay-at91_git.bb#L51

Answer (score 0):

###### In Short

The short answer is, normally, unless you've tempered with the `etc/fstab` file, the boot partition is mounted in `/boot`. Yo can check that it is indeed the boot partition that is mounted with the `df` command.

###### fstab

Now I'm a bit of a `fstab` noob myself but here is what I could get from it.
In the [fstab file](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/etc-fstab) is the file responsible for automatically mounting device. In general, by default yocto generates a fstab file looking like this:

```sh
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot   vfat    defaults    0   0
```

Meaning (from what I can get) that your first partition will be mounted in /boot automatically. (If there are any fstab wizard out here feel free to elaborate)

###### From my experience

This work as normally mounted folder. You can modify all you want in `/boot` and the changes will happen on the `boot` partition. Once your changes are done, reboot and you should be able to see your changes having taken effect.

###### As for your questions

I have a broad idea but I suspect this depends on your build and target.
And I have no yocto build I can check that with atm. So here are my hints:

- Do you need it? I don't think so... unless you have a module or a script that is supposed to automatically mess with the boot partition... and even so I don't think this is vital. I'd the fastest way to find out is to remove the line from `/etc/fstab` mounting the boot partition and see if somthing crashes
- Who is it used by? I suspect no one. I think that it is just a handy way to access your boot partition buas I said, haven't had the opportunity to confirm that.
- How do you prevent yocto from creating it? All you should need to do is tell yocto to write a fstab file without the line mounting `/boot`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605656/how-to-overwrite-linux-system-files-into-the-yocto-filesystem) is how to override a file installed by a parent layer. Know that fstab is installed by `/poky/meta/recipes-core/basefiles/base-files_X.X.X.bb`.

Note that overall I'm not a 100% certain what `/boot` this is used for but I wouldn't recommend getting rid of it. In my opinion there is no draw backs to having your boot partition mounted and it is a handy tool to check on your boot partition while investigating your build.

Comment: fstab doesnt mount /boot and also the contents is different between the rootfs /boot and partition. I didnt check with df, will try that tomororw - I did however try mountpoint on /boot and it came back as nothing. Also one of the output files <image-name>.rootfs.gz has a boot folder in it - so I think its safe to say its not mounted from the partition

Comment: @gcb Ok that's intersting. What target are you building for?

Comment: Also, may I ask what is in your fstab?... I suspect mine was actually very specific to my build, my answer might have been a bit misinformed, sorry

Comment: The only thing I do in my fstab is mount an spi flash drive. The targert is for atmel sama5d27 - maybe they are adding this boot folder in their own recipies. I use their uboot and bootstrap. If this is strange/not expected behavior maybe its worth asking them also

Comment: Hum... ok yeah I'm sorry I can't help any further.  It is probable that they add or at least populate the `\boot` folder in their layer. I haven't worked with this target and this issue seem related to your hardware meta-layer...I think it is indeed worth asking atmel or whoever wrote the layer you're using.

Comment: Think I found it: https://github.com/linux4sam/meta-atmel/blob/07867084ec52b5580e55eb67c861823eaab5e4c3/recipes-bsp/dt-overlay-at91/dt-overlay-at91_git.bb#L51 they copy the overlays files to /boot! So I just need to somehow disable this or delete the /boot folder. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @gcb Oh it is from an overlay! Hum... if it was coded right you might actually need this folder to make the overlay work

Comment: The overlays from atmel are mainly for different screens - can safely remove I think! Thanks!